# Many loginTokens in Mongodb due to Meteor.js Accounts

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

When looking through the `Users` collection in Mongodb, it appears that the Meteor.js Accounts package has created many `loginTokens` under `services.resume.loginTokens`.

Is this normal? Is there a need to limit the number of loginTokens or set some form of expiration for these tokens?

Answer (score 5):

This is normal, each unique browser login has its own token.

If you use the node-ddp or a third party ddp package you're likely to have a higher than average number of tokens. Many libraries log in directly with the username/password without attempting to use previously assigned tokens. Meteor sees each of them as unique browsers and assigns a unique token to each login session, so they tend to build up.

To expire tokens sooner you can use the `Accounts.config(options)` with the `loginExpirationInDays` to something smaller (defaults at 90 days):

```
Accounts.config({
    loginExpirationInDays: 7 //Expire loginTokens older than a week.
});
```